# Associate model class with entire row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I associate my model class with entire row in JTable in order to get link to model class by row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry, but I can't see how can I get
>   MyBusinessObject instance associated
>   with specified row

Well, you would need to add a getRow(...) method to return the appropriate business object.

I've written a generic RowTableModel that does this. It is an Abstract class however, you might be able to use the [BeanTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) which extends the RowTableModel. Or the example shows you how to easily extend RowTableModel by implementing a couple of methods.

Edit:

Add the following two lines to the end of the example:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
JButton first = model.getRow(0);
System.out.println(first);
```

Comment: it seems like a correct way. One little question about usage: ((RowTableModel<MyClass>)jtable.getModel()).getRow(row)?

Comment: I don't see a question but I added a simple example above based on the JButtonTableModel example.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) which will work for any Domain Model object that follows Java Beans conventions (getter/setter).

Documentation is very good and there are good examples too.

GlazedLists also brings other interesting features (eg filtering), should you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You handle this by defining an implementation of TableModel.  (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)  Your TableModel class can store your data however you like.  So, for example, you could have a list of objects where each element in the list represents an entire row.

Comment: OK, if so, how can I get row-model by row index? The only apropriate method I see - getValueAt() is used for rendering and column dependent.

Comment: See my solution: The underlying data structure is a List whereby the list index is the model index and independent from the view changing (e.g. if the JTable is sorted).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define underlying business object:
public class MyBusinessObject {
  private final int i;
  private final double d;
  private final String s;

  public MyBusinessObject(int i, double d, String s) {
    this.i = i;
    this.d = d;
    this.s = s;
  }

  public int getI() { return i; }
  public double getD() { return d; }
  public String getS() { return s; }
}

// Define TableModel implementation that "sits on" MyBusinessObject:
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "i", "d", "s" };
  private static final Class<?>[] COLUMN_CLASSES = { Integer.class, Double.class, String.class };

  static {
    assert COLUMN_NAMES.length == COLUMN_CLASSES.length;
  }

  // Collection of business objects.  Use ArrayList for efficient random access.
  private final List<MyBusinessObject> bizObj = new ArrayList<MyBusinessObject>();

  // TableModel methods delegate through to collection of MyBusinessObject.
  public int getColumnCount() { return COLUMN_NAMES.length; }
  public String[] getColumnNames() { return COLUMN_NAMES; }
  public Class<?>[] getColumnClasses() { return COLUMN_CLASSES; }
  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object ret;
    MyBusinessObject bo = bizObj.get(row);

    switch(col) {
      case 1:
        ret = bo.getI();
        break;
      case 2:
        ret = bo.getD();
        break;
      case 3:
        ret = bo.getS();
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column index: " + col);
    }

    return ret;
  }

  // Additional methods for updating the collection.
  public void addBusinessObject(MyBusinessObject bo) {
    bizObj.add(bo);
    int i = bizObj.size() - 1;
    fireTableRowsInserted(i, i);
  }

  // ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see how can I get MyBusinessObject instance associated with specified row frow your example